# correct routes configuration in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I created two tables with the corresponding controllers with the CRUD methods.This is what I have in routes.rb:

```
 resources :employees

 resources :tasks
```

Now, I want to be able to assign/unassign tasks to employees (There's a many to manny association bentween employees and tasks). Would it be okay to nest resources :employees inside resources :tasks
So my routes.rb would have

```
resources :employees
  resources :tasks

  resources :tasks do
  resources :employee
   end
```

and if that's ok to use, do I need to create a different controller for the methods I want to use to assign employees to tasks. Like a employeetask controller.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the Nested Resources section of the rails guide:

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

The example they give is:

```
class Magazine < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :ads
end

class Ad < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :magazine
end
```

With the correpsonding routes:

```
resources :magazines do
  resources :ads
end
```

Which generates:

```
HTTP Verb   Path    Controller#Action   Used for
GET /magazines/:magazine_id/ads ads#index   display a list of all ads for a specific magazine
GET /magazines/:magazine_id/ads/new ads#new return an HTML form for creating a new ad belonging to a specific magazine
POST    /magazines/:magazine_id/ads ads#create  create a new ad belonging to a specific magazine
GET /magazines/:magazine_id/ads/:id ads#show    display a specific ad belonging to a specific magazine
GET /magazines/:magazine_id/ads/:id/edit    ads#edit    return an HTML form for editing an ad belonging to a specific magazine
PATCH/PUT   /magazines/:magazine_id/ads/:id ads#update  update a specific ad belonging to a specific magazine
DELETE  /magazines/:magazine_id/ads/:id ads#destroy delete a specific ad belonging to a specific magazine
```

If you wanted to setup a special controller to handle the relationship, then in your case you would do:

```
...
...

resources :tasks do
  resources :employee, controller: 'task_employees'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you do:

```
resources :employees do 
  resources :tasks, only: [:index, :new, :create]
end

resources :tasks do
  resources :employees, only: [:index, :new, :create]
end
```

Which will give you (running `rake routes` in your console):

```
   employee_tasks GET    /employees/:employee_id/tasks(.:format)        tasks#index
                  POST   /employees/:employee_id/tasks(.:format)        tasks#create
new_employee_task GET    /employees/:employee_id/tasks/new(.:format)    tasks#new
        employees GET    /employees(.:format)                           employees#index
                  POST   /employees(.:format)                           employees#create
     new_employee GET    /employees/new(.:format)                       employees#new
    edit_employee GET    /employees/:id/edit(.:format)                  employees#edit
         employee GET    /employees/:id(.:format)                       employees#show
                  PATCH  /employees/:id(.:format)                       employees#update
                  PUT    /employees/:id(.:format)                       employees#update
                  DELETE /employees/:id(.:format)                       employees#destroy
   task_employees GET    /tasks/:task_id/employees(.:format)            employees#index
                  POST   /tasks/:task_id/employees(.:format)            employees#create
new_task_employee GET    /tasks/:task_id/employees/new(.:format)        employees#new
            tasks GET    /tasks(.:format)                               tasks#index
                  POST   /tasks(.:format)                               tasks#create
         new_task GET    /tasks/new(.:format)                           tasks#new
                  GET    /tasks/:id/edit(.:format)                      tasks#edit
                  GET    /tasks/:id(.:format)                           tasks#show
                  PATCH  /tasks/:id(.:format)                           tasks#update
                  PUT    /tasks/:id(.:format)                           tasks#update
                  DELETE /tasks/:id(.:format)                           tasks#destroy
```

As you can see, you only need the `TasksController` and the `EmployeesController`. You do not need any additional controllers.

Note that in the `new` action of the `TasksController`, you may or may not have a `:employee_id` param as indicated in these two route declarations from above:

```
new_employee_task GET    /employees/:employee_id/tasks/new(.:format)    tasks#new
         new_task GET    /tasks/new(.:format)                           tasks#new
```

So, you might want to do something like:

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController

  def new
    if @employee = Employee.find_by(id: params[:employee_id])
      @task = @employee.tasks.build(task_params)
    else
      @task = Task.new(task_params)
    end
    ...
  end

end
```

You would need to do something similar for the `index` and `create` actions. And, you would want to do something similar in the `EmployeesController` for the `index`, `create`, and `new` actions.